# How can I give linux hosted logs as input path in filebeat.yml?

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I've linux hosted application which has logs and i want to harvest them with use filebeat.
How can i give input path in filebeat.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a filebeat installed on the linux system. You can configure filebeat to use log input and point the path to location where the logs reside.
Check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html).

Simple Example :

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /usr/share/apps/logs/*.log
output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}'
```

Comment: No I don't have installed filebeat in linux system, I installed filbeat in my pc(local). But i have application with log  which is hosted in linux server.I want see those logs in kibana(local installed in my pc).

Comment: Please read the FileBeat Overview -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-overview.html. It can only forward logs that it can physically access. In your case you either need to put a filebeat shipper on the linux server that forwards them to a local Elastic Setup or simply copy the logs to your local PC and user filebeat and/or logstash to ship logs to local Elastic setup.

Comment: @BhavinVarsur was my answer helpful? are you able to ingest the logs using filebeat ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.but can use tcp input as filebat input to get the log from my linux hosted application

Comment: But how will your remote system push logs to that TCP input of Filebeat ? Are you planning to use rsyslog, flume  or something to push them ?

Comment: I don't know that's why i'm asking question

Comment: I understand :) . I am saying you would not be able to do that. Hence the suggestion to install FileBeat on Linux to forward it to Logstash. Logstash will push to Elastic. Let me share a Docker Compose file that does that, maybe that will help.

Comment: I didn't have docker file